# Create various APK with various icons and splashscreens

Tags: android, apk

I want to create various APK of my android project, with different SplashScreen/icon versions for each APK.

e.g :

```
APK1 : SplashScreen = @drawable/splashscreen1
       IconLauncher = android:icon="@drawable/icone_launcher1"

APK2 : SplashScreen = @drawable/splashscreen2
       IconLauncher = android:icon="@drawable/icone_launcher2"
```

Is there a "practical" way to do this ? I prefer not to copy/paste folders of my code so I can keep my code from redundancy, and when I want to make improvements of one APK, I want those improvements to appear on the others.

Any clue ? Maybe some kind of script that will duplicate my code in different folders and only change the AndroidManifest.xml containing the style of my launcher activity (defining the splashcreen) and the launcher icon also ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you use Maven, it is pretty easy, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699485/skinning-android-app-with-maven-build-profiles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions for this problem. 
First solution is using Ant.

Second, which I prefer, is by using android library. Make actual project as android library. Than, in your case, create two projects which will be using this library. Than change icon for specified project by adding it to drawable folder of new created projects.

E.g. if you want to change "drawable-hdpi/icon.png" from library just add to your new project changed icon in "drawable-hdpi/icon.png".

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I used the library method, simple to make it work and very efficient !

Answer (score 0):

i guess the easiest thing is to upload it to a SVN and after you finish "committing" on one of them, just run "get" on another..